# Как программно определить статус активации чекбоксов на экране с использованием методов isDisplayed(), isSelected(), и isEnabled()?

Tags: java, appium

На экране отображено 10 чекбоксов, из которых 3 активированы.
Необходимо проверить статусы всех 10 чекбоксов.

Используя методы **isDisplayed()**, **isSelected()**, и **isEnabled()**, не удалось достичь желаемого результата.

Как можно определить статус чекбокса?

Answer (score 0):

Для радиобаттона проверяется индекс выбранного элемента (-1, если не выбрано ничего)

Comment: Допустим у меня 7 радиобатонов, выбран 4, как мне провериить остальные ?

Comment: Выбран может быть один. Зачем остальные проверять?

Comment: Что бы быть увереным, что он отрабатывает корректно. Тест тыкаем на все радиобаттоны